# AWS Org & Azure AD SSO - Sign In Issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, aws-organizations

after hours of debugging powershell and IAM permission errors, I'm almost done creating an Azure AD to AWS Org SSO PoC. I've been following [this guide](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-automate-saml-federation-to-multiple-aws-accounts-from-microsoft-azure-active-directory/) and the last bit of it is to visit this link http://myapps.microsoft.com, and then magic is supposed to happen.... but it doesn't :(. For some reason, I'm getting prompted for credentials from Microsoft even though I'm logged in, and I've tried many combinations of my userID login to get in. Has anyone come across this issue (screenshot) when attempting to get Azure AD and AWS Orgs. I've double checked my attributes/claims & registration manifest but can't pinpoint the cause. Any help would be much appreciated, and if I find the root cause I'll be sure to post the resolution.

Not sure if this is helpful, but after I put in my creds, it redirects me to this link:
`https://account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com/applications/redirecttoapplication.aspx?error=access_denied&error_description=AADSTS650057%3a+Invalid+resource.+The+client+has+requested+access+to+a+resource+which+is+not+listed+in+the+requested+permissions+in+the+client%27s+application+registration.+Client+app+ID%3a+0000000c-0000-0000-c000-000000000000(Microsoft+App+Access+Panel).+Resource+value+from+request%3a+84c029fc-2409-4373-a521-9e8fc98b78df.+Resource+app+ID%3a+84c029fc-2409-4373-a521-9e8fc98b78df.+List+of+valid+resources+from+app+registration%3a+.%0d%0aTrace+ID%3a+7c91fc7e-37c5-42e6-bebd-ab66fc113400%0d%0aCorrelation+ID%3a+50aa777c-7fc1-4a17-8a56-fe22944257f8%0d%0aTimestamp%3a+2019-06-21+21%3a00%3a30Z&state=U2luZ2xlU2lnbk9uVHlwZT1QYXNzd29yZCZvcGVyYXRpb249QXV0aENvZGUmYXBwbGljYXRpb25JZD04NGMwMjlmYy0yNDA5LTQzNzMtYTUyMS05ZThmYzk4Yjc4ZGYmYWNjb3VudD0%3d`

[image: Another Login O.o]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my issue, I had a problem with my basic SAML configuration in the Azure portal. By default the `Entity ID` was placed as a `placeholder` and never actually saved to be `https://signin.aws.amazon.com/saml`. Once I went in there, selected modify, and pasted it in, everything worked as expected and I was able to assume the role. Hope this helps folks in the future.